# Connect to Cassandra via Kundera using SSL

Tags: ssl, cassandra, persistence, kundera

We are using Kundera to connect to Cassandra, which is working just fine. Now we had to move Cassandra to a distant server what required to encrypt the connections. There is no problem using native Cassandra driver, however we have no clue, how to do that with Kundera.

There is a complete lack of documentation. Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to Cassandra using Kundera after encryption? Can you share any error logs or so?

Comment: Honestly, I even don't know how to set it up. There is nothing about SSL in Kundera documentation. There is a description of load balancing and stuff like that but nothing about encryption. No equivalent of .withSSL() method. If you have any example, please, could you kindly provide?